# Performance issue when angular directive is called more number of times on page

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created an angular directive which is for adding span tags of error messages below input textboxes. I wanted to reduce the lines of codes so made an angular directive for that.

Now the question is, can there be the performance issue if there are more number of textboxes on page? As the number of textboxes will increase, the directive will be called more number of times.

The directive contains one div tag and 2 span tags which are compiled at the end of the directive in link function. There is no `$watch` in the directive.

Will this degrade the performance? Should I go ahead with using this directive approach or should I use conventional approach of writing all those div and span tags below the input text?

Comment: What profiling tools do You use?

Comment: The performance get affected by number of reasons, such as number of watches added. In your case i don't see that been a major issue. Google on AngularJS performance and try to understand what are the things that can cause these performance issues. Also remember lot of these performance issues come into picture when there is a lot of data on the page.